# Error while deploying to Tomcat: tomcatManager status code:404, ReasonPhrase:Not Found

Tags: java, tomcat7

I had a problem in creating Spring configuration in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461319/tomcat-fail-application-at-context-path-employee-could-not-be-started#comment20143215_14461319)

Now I am trying to deploy my war file from IntelliJ IDEA to tomcat 7 with tomcat7-maven-plugin and I am facing another problem.

this is pom.xml settings for that:

```
<build>
    <finalName>employee-list</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/employee-list</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <path>/employee-list</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this is web.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


<display-name>employee-list</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC configurations-->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/employee/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security configurations-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

So, I use `org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy -e`tomcat7-maven-plugin
and get this debug log:

```
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy (default-cli) @ employee <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy (default-cli) @ employee ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://127.0.0.1:8080/employee-list  
Uploading: http://127.0.0.1:8080/employee-list/deploy?path=%2Femployee-list
Uploaded: http://127.0.0.1:8080/employee-list/deploy?path=%2Femployee-list (27914 KB at 8258.5 KB/sec)

[INFO] tomcatManager status code:404, ReasonPhrase:Not Found
[INFO] <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.28 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource () is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.28</h3></body></html>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.686s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 23 22:03:27 EET 2013
```

in localhost_access_log I get this line:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jan/2013:22:03:23 +0200] "PUT /employee-list/deploy?path=%2Femployee-list HTTP/1.1" 404 952
```

in tomcat7-stdout I get:

```
янв 23, 2013 9:44:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/employee-list/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/employee-list/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 25; columnNumber: 15; Error at (25, 15) : org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2719)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1054)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)

    ...

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1770)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:855)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1051)
    ... 46 more

янв 23, 2013 9:44:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
SEVERE: Occurred at line 25 column 15
янв 23, 2013 9:44:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
янв 23, 2013 9:44:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
янв 23, 2013 9:44:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/employee-list] startup failed due to previous errors
```

line25 is on the end of  bean:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

**can someone tell where I go wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<url>` in configuration of `tomcat7-maven-plugin` is a Tomcat manager URL, not an application URL:

```
<url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html</url>
```

**See also:**

- [`tomcat7:deploy`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html)

Comment: axtavt, thnanks! it does work - I managed to deploy my project